# Dates and intervals in SAS

Tags: sas

If I have two dates e.g. 22MAR2005 to 01MAR2006 and I want to create season intervals (spring, summer, autumn, winter) based on this interval, how can this be done in a data step?

Season's are defined as:
  Spring: March to May
  Summer: June to August
  Autumn: September to November 
  Winter: December to February

I need to calculate how long they spent in each season.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers...

Comment: Realized my answer may not be what you're looking for. Can you clarify what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that to MONTH first and then to SEASON. This exact question was asked recently so it's relatively easy to find via search (I'm assuming some course is using this as homework?).

```
 data want;
   set have;

   *create month;
    month_date = month(date);

   *assign to season;
   if month_date in (6, 7, 8) then season = 'Summer';
   else if month_date in (9, 10, 11) then season ='Fall';
   ....etc;
run;
```

You could also use a format but since you're just starting out this is likely easier.

Other users question which seems really really similar:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/proc-glm/m-p/492142

EDIT: Use INTCK() to calculate the number of intervals. 
Then use INTNX to increment across the intervals and count your days. 
How you align your dates can be controlled with the first parameter to the INTNX() function. You can check the documentation for the exact specifics.

```
data want;

    start_date="22Mar2005"d;
    end_date="01Mar2006"d;
    num_intervals=intck('quarter', start_date, end_date, 'C') ;

    do interval=0 to num_intervals;
        season_start=intnx('Month3.3', start_date, interval, 'b');
        season_end=intnx('Month3.3', start_date, interval, 'e');
        Number_Days=season_end - season_start + 1;
        output;
    end;
    format start_date end_date season: yymmddd10.;

run;
```

Comment: Thanks, that does help.  I want to be able to work out (in days) how long was spent in each season.  If we assume the season begins at the first of the month and lasts until the end of the month?  Thanks.